# Oracle Database using SID as service name

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

An application I'm working on connects to a database using the service name. The expected format is `<SID>.<domain>`. However, the application can't connect to the database using this as the service name.

There are 9 databases running on this server. I can connect to all of the other databases using that format for the service name (through the application or SQL developer). For some reason I can connect to this one using just the SID as the service name -- but not with the domain.

As you can see from the tns listener status below, it's using the SID alone for this database as the service name. I should also say that the pfiles for both of the databases I looked at for comparison had the same values.

`listener.ora`:

```
<...>
 LISTENER_<this sid> =
  (DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<hostname>.<domain>)(PORT=1521)))
SID_LIST_LISTENER_KS=
   (SID_LIST=
        (SID_DESC=
          (GLOBAL_DBNAME=<this sid>.<domain>)
          (SID_NAME=<this sid>)
          (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1)
        )
    )

 LISTENER_<other sid> =
  (DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<hostname>.<domain>)(PORT=1521)))
SID_LIST_LISTENER_KS=
   (SID_LIST=
        (SID_DESC=
          (GLOBAL_DBNAME=<other sid>.<domain>)
          (SID_NAME=<other sid>)
          (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1)
        )
    )

<...>
```

`tnsnames.ora`:

```
<...>
<this sid> =
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <hostname>.<domain>)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = <this sid>.<domain>)))
<other sid> =
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <hostname>.<domain>)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = <other sid>.<domain>)))
<...>
```

tns listener status:

```
$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 07-MAR-2019 10:24:48

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                07-MAR-2019 08:46:13
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 38 min. 35 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/<hostname>/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<hostname>.<domain>)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
<...>
Service "<this sid>" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "<this sid>", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "<this sid>XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "<this sid>", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "<other sid>.<domain>" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "<other sid>", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "<other sid>XDB.<domain>" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "<other sid>", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
<...>
The command completed successfully
```

Error message when I use the `<sid>.<domain>` as service name:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check db_name,db_domain and select global_name from global_name;

Comment: It turns out this was the answer. The pfile I had was correct but evidently the running configuration and/or spfile wasn't. I resolved the issue by issuing `create pfile='/path/to/pfile' from memory;` and checked the newly formed pfile. Sure enough, there was no `db_domain` specified.